# Lipschitz continuity: a question about a detail of the definition

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

There is a particular detail about Lipschitz continuity about which I am unsure. I would define Lipschitz continuity as follows. For simplcity I assume a real-valued function on the real line. Is the following correct?

There exists positive constants a and b such both $\vert x-x_0\vert < a$ AND $ \vert f(x) - f(x_0)\vert < b \vert x-x_0 \vert$ are true. Note that I do NOT require: Given $b$ there exists $a$ etc etc, or vice versa. I merely require that the constants $a$ and $b$ exist.

This does not exclude the if $b$ then $a$ .... relationship, it merely is not required. The inverse - if $a$ then $b$ -  is also allowed, which gives a lot of flexibility.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So you are saying, that a function is Lipschitz continuous at some point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ if the above holds for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$? Or that this holds true, given that the function is Lipschitz at some point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Your definition does not make sense as written because you have not explained how $x$ and $x_0$ are quantified. And even if you intended to write "there exist $a,b>0$ such that for all $x,x_0 \in \mathbb R$, $|x-x_0| < a$ and $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < b|x-x_0|$", then no function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is Lipschitz, because if $x_0=0$ and $x=2a$ then $|x-x_0|<a$ is false.

Comment: I'll start again. Consider Lipschitz continuity **at a point** . f real-valued function of one variable. Let f:V->W, V, W open intervals, and two **pre-defined** intervals S = {x0-p, x0+p) in V and T=( f(x0)-q, f(x0)+q ) in W.   Is f Lipschitz continuous at x0 when there is a constant M such that |f(x) - f(x0)| < M|x-x0| for all x in S and all f(x) in T? Obviously I could define many possible open intervals S and T. All I need is one pair of intervals (with the right condition as above) in order to have Lipschitz continuity at x0. This condition certainly implies ordinary continuity.